# Php, bash, sshpass, scp is not working via shell_exec

Tags: php, bash

**Issue**

I have `php`, which run `bash` script via `shell_exec`. All is ok, but last step (`scp` to server) false.

```
sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' scp ../xlsx/"${file_pdf%.*}-$i.xlsx" USER@HOST:/var/www/html/FOLDER 2>&1
```

Output.

```
Host key verification failed.
```

When I run this script as user on server, all is ok. Is something needed to run `scp` (or connect) via user `www-data`? Rights are `777` for folders.

Thanks.

Comment: Because user is www-data. See output of "cat /etc/passwd | grep www-data". It's /usr/sbin/nologin? If yes, you can modify it or use sudo for command.

Comment: Add in /etc/sudoers: "www-data  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sshpass" and add sudo to your cmd

Comment: And you can try add ssh option to scp command: "sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ../xlsx/"${file_pdf%.*}-$i.xlsx" USER@HOST:/var/www/html/FOLDER 2>&1"

Comment: @Šerg Yes, thanks, it works, I tried while you answer this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution.

I added option `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to `scp`.

```
sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ../xlsx/"${file_pdf%.*}-$i.xlsx" USER@HOST:/var/www/html/FOLDER 2>&1
```